# How to create redux strore with object using typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I am new to using **Redux** and **Typescript**. And I can’t understand the error why the **store** doesn’t want to accept the **reducer** when i try to work with object

```
let store = createStore(counter); //error on counter
```

it’s the wrong **type** set in **Typescript** or the wrong **reducer**?

error text:

> const counter: (state: IPerson, action: any) => number | undefined
> No overload matches this call.
> Contribute a translation for #2769
>
> Overload 1 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<IPerson, any>, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<unknown, unknown> | undefined): Store<IPerson, any>', gave the following error.
> Contribute a translation for #2772
>
> Argument of type '(state: IPerson, action: any) => number | undefined' is not assignable to >parameter of type 'Reducer<IPerson, any>'.
> Translation: I was expecting Reducer<IPerson, any>, but you passed (state: IPerson, action: any) => number | undefined

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import {createStore} from 'redux'

function App() {

interface IPerson{
  name:string,
  age:number
}

const increment = () => {return {type: 'INCREMENT'}}
const decrement = () => {return {type: 'DECREMENT'}}

const counter = (state:IPerson , action:any) =>{
  switch(action.type){
    case'INCREMENT':
      return state.age + 1;
      
    case'DECREMENT':
      return state.age - 1;
  }}
let store = createStore(counter);

store.subscribe(()=>console.log(store.getState()));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={(()=>store.dispatch(increment()))}>increment</button>
      <button onClick={(()=>store.dispatch(decrement()))}>decrement</button>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reducer does not `return` in case the other two cases didn't match.

Generally, you are using a very old style of Redux here (modern Redux is 1/4 of the code) and quite some bad practices (never call `store.dispatch` in a component!).

I would **really** recommend you to read about [modern Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and follow the [official tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) instead of following whatever resources you've been reading so far.